# tomcat8 at 100% cpu when trying https on port 80

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, tomcat8

When trying to connect to tomcat 8 using https://localhost:8080/ tomcat get stuck at 100% cpu with `ip - - [12/Jan/2017:12:14:23 +0100] "-" 400 - -` in the access_log and

```
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:50 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

in catalina.out

On firefox I get

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

I tried with tomcat8 with the default configuration (fresh install on debian 8) and the same thing is happening. I know I shouldn't try https on port 8080 or 80 but I get those requests on my server and I have to restart tomcat to fix the 100% cpu utilization

Comment: Yes, I don't have that problem with http://

Comment: This might be a tomcat bug, can someone reproduce it to confirm that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tomcat bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57544

> This has been fixed in trunk (9.0.x development), 8.0.x for 8.0.19
>   onwards and 7.0.x for 7.0.60 onwards.